# numpy bytes to plain string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `X` with `dtype 'S' (numpy.bytes_)`. For example printing `print(X[0, 0])` yields `b'somestring'`. Similarly `str(X[0, 0])` returns string `"b'somestring'"`.

However I need to print or convert to string so that it does not contain `b'` at the beginning and `'` at the end. I just want to print `somestring` or return a string `"somestring"`. How to do it?

Note: I cannot change the type of the array.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You just need to decode the string back into ASCII, so it would just be:

```
bytes_string.decode('UTF-8')
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> b'somestring'.decode('UTF-8')
'somestring'
```

Comment: how about a whole array and not just one element?

Comment: You could do `X.astype(str)`, although I'm not sure exactly how this performs the decoding.